# NSFetchRequest not working with predicate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I have this code:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Entry"];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"version == %@", @"1.0"];

[request setPredicate:predicate];

NSArray *results = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
```

The entity "Entry" has an attribute called "version", which is a string. The predicate above doesn't seem to only be returning entries with the string as "1.0" though, returning some entries which are set to "1.1".

Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: did you try with just = instead of ==?

Comment: The predicate looks fine to me. Have you tried something else?

Answer (score 1):

Try putting round braces () around your predicate expression

i.e.

```
"(version == %@)"
```

Answer (score 1):

have a look at the [apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html)'s

and try it with `like` in case of `==`  or:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:  
                                       @"(version == %@)", @"1.0"];
```